# trying to get a regex to match ranges

Tags: javascript, regex

So far I have `^(\d.*[.]?\d*)|([<>][=]?\d.*[.]?\d*)|(\d.*[.]?\d*[-]\d.*[.]?\d*)$` but with my testing I get:

Should Match: (all do)

```
>1
<9
>=99
<=123123.134
1-2
44.421-234.123
123
123.123
0.123
```

Should not match: (examples marked with * are matching when they shouldn't)

```
123.      *
.123
=<123     *
=>234     *
sdf
sdf.sdf
123.sdf   *
```

Example [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5Cd.%2a%5B.%5D%3F%5Cd%2a%29%7C%28%5B%3C%3E%5D%5B%3D%5D%3F%5Cd.%2a%5B.%5D%3F%5Cd%2a%29%7C%28%5Cd.%2a%5B.%5D%3F%5Cd%2a%5B-%5D%5Cd.%2a%5B.%5D%3F%5Cd%2a%29%24&input=%3E1%0A%3C9%0A%3E%3D99%0A%3C%3D123123.134%0A1-2%0A44.421-234.123%0A123%0A123.123%0A0.123%0A%0A%0A123.%0A.123%0A%3D%3C123%0A%3D%3E234%0Asdf%0Asdf.sdf%0A123.sdf%0A).

Comment: Match your characters except `*` ?

Comment: @RahilWazir - The * in the should not match is just marking the examples are are incorrectly matching. Hopefully cleared that up the question.

Comment: How do you define a range? did you mean something like this? `digit[. or - or < or >]digit`. if tha'ts the case, you're regex seems over- complicated.

Comment: @Justin808 How about [this](http://regex101.com/r/gL0dH6)?

Comment: The sub-expression `/\d.*/` could be a problem if you have characters and digits mixed. `"123=".match(/\d.*/) matches ["123="]`. see? you might want `\d+` or `\d*` (which you used occasionally)

Comment: @TastySpaceApple - I think \d+ is what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Jerry - That works, though the group stuff is beyond my knowledge at the moment. If you write up an answer I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this maybe:

```
^(?:[<>]?=?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

I trust that you already know how the anchors `^` and `$` work.

`(?: ... )` is a non-capture group, it's the same as a capture group `( ... )` except that it doesn't 'save' the matched parts. This is particular useful when you don't really need the matched part and you want to improve the efficiency, when compared to `( ... )` which takes a little overhead to store extra data.

`[<>]?=?` is for potential comparators.

`\d+(?:\.\d+)?` is used for numbers, integers or floating and ensure that there is no such thing as `123.` or `.123` since we are using the `+` quantifier on the `\d`.

So the regex matches a comparator followed by a number, or a subtraction between two numbers:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)?
+-----------+|+-----------+
   1st num   |   2nd num
         minus sign
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gL0dH6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^(?:[<>]=?|\d+(?:.\d+)?-)?\d+(?:.\d+)?$
```

Comment: @Justin808: and what do you think about that?